# search within a certain coumn in a pandas DataFrame for string and then print the whole row

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I imported a txt file and converted it to a pandas DataFrame. (pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv) I want to search within one column for a certain pattern that looks like this: t=0. For example "text text text text t=10 text text". the number after the equal signs varies by row and I want all rows that contain this pattern to be printed. I tried it by applying regular expressions but the following message appears:
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Can you help me out?

Best regards

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Giving a dummy dataset, what you tried and expected results, will attract many helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `contains` function from `str` module:

```
mask = df['column_with_text'].str.contains('t=0', na =False,regex=True)

# keep columns matching what we want
df[mask]['column_with_text']
```

From there you can choose to print them in a loop.

Comment: Thank you very much. Out of curiosity if I wanted to extract a group, why can't I use extract instead of contains? When I try it I get the error message: extract() got an unexpected keyword argument 'na'. How could I extract the group while at the same time dealing with naN values?

Comment: str.extract https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html ;)